# Set up the Laravel and Vue JS in same apache

Tags: laravel, vue.js, apache

I would like to host a Laravel and VueJs in the same apache. They are separate project which Laravel is for API and VueJs is for CMS. Now I can run the VueJS perfectly. But I do not know how to run the Laravel too. Here is the 000-default.config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vue_project/dist

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html/vue_project/dist>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I add the laravel project in this 000-default.conf? How do I need to create another site-available conf file? Thanks for all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly there, create another file, for example `001-laravel.conf` with this content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel_project/public

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And that should be enough for it to work. Of course use the right path on `DocumentRoot`, it must point to the `public` folder.

Once you have done this, if you are on linux, run `sudo a2ensite 001-laravel`, and then `sudo service apache2 restart` so it loads the new config page.

But have in mind that you need to add `ServerName your-test-page.local` or something like that, so you can specify that, when you access `your-test-page.local`, Apache correctly resolves it to Laravel and not VueJS.

You also then need to edit your `hosts` file, and add that alias to `127.0.0.1`... Look for a tutorial on how to do this, as there is plenty of information about this...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although this answer is not suitable in my case. But your answer can help another one which need to host multiple project in testing server. I will give this answer as the most helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that I can use the `Alias` to solve this problem. Here is my 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vue_project/dist
        Alias /apis /var/www/html/laravel_project/public
       
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/html/vue_project/dist>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/laravel_project>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

First add the `Alias` of the laravel. Remember to **include the public folder**.

Second add the directory of the laravel. **Do not add public folder** in the directory.

Once the config is done. Run `sudo systemctl restart apache2` or `sudo service apache2 restart`. Then refresh the page and we can use alias to get into laravel project with same domain.